# Using global variables in unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm unit testing a function, e.g. one that checks if the number you've given equals a global const variable. (Simplified situation)

```
def the_special_number = 7

def is_the_special_number(number):
    if (number == the_special_number):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

When I'm testing this function, I'd write a test like:

```
import unittest

def test_is_special_number_true(self):
    self.assertTrue(is_the_special_number(the_special_number))
```

But is this actually a valid unit test, since in the function and the unit test I'm using the same global const? 
Or does the assertTrue need to be replaced with the following:

```
self.assertTrue(is_the_special_number(7))
```

Comment: Do you want your test to verify that your function works for whatever is the value of `the_special_number` ? Or do you want to test that your function works for the number 7? If `the_special_number` was changed, would you want your test to fail, or to pass?

Comment: It needs to work for whatever the_special_number is.
I guess the test can still pass

Comment: Then use `the_special_number` in your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it dynamic u can use the variable `the_special_number`, thanks to khelwood